# Using Pickle in Flask

Tags: python, flask, pickle, importerror

I recently moved some code I've been using successfully into a flask server. It has worked seamlessly until now off the server.

However, in the same directory, when trying to load a stored object using pickle, I get an `ImportError`. This happens in a function which runs when `@app.before_first_request` is called.

How could this change cause this? Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your code? It dosen’t particularly sound like a problem of Pickle or Flask.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Flask change the paths that are searched for imports, adding `sys.path.append('./')` to the beginning of my app's file fixed the problem.